# Mapping an entity with a entity reference to a DTO cnot returning the values of the referenced entity - .NET Core, AutoMapper

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, automapper

Recently I have created an entity which has a one-to-one relation with another entity. I am trying to retrieve all the values of the main entity AND all the values of the referenced entity by using a DTO class in my API GET endpoint (of that entity), but with little success

For some other entities I have created several DTO classes and these work fine, however these other entities don't have a referenced entity of which I want to get the values.

The one-to-one (FK) relation is set up as follow:

**The main entity:**

```
public class Commodity
{
    public Commodity()
    {
    }

    public long CommodityID { get; set; }

    public long OMSCommodityMaterialID { get; set; }

    public decimal? SpecficWeight { get; set; }

    public virtual OmsCommodityMaterial OmsCommodityMaterial { get; set; }
}
```

**The referenced entity:**

```
public class OmsCommodityMaterial
{
    public OmsCommodityMaterial()
    {
    }

    public long? CommodityMaterialID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public long? SortOrder { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Commodity Commodity { get; set; }
}
```

With FLUENT API I am defining the one-to-one relation:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Commodity>(entity =>
{
    entity.Property(e => e.CommodityID)
        .HasColumnName("CommodityID")
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

    entity.Property(e => e.OMSCommodityMaterialID)
        .HasColumnName("OMSCommodityMaterialID");

    entity.Property(e => e.SpecficWeight)
        .HasColumnName("SpecficWeight")
        .HasColumnType("decimal(18, 2)");

    entity.HasOne(a => a.OmsCommodityMaterial)
        .WithOne(b => b.Commodity)
        .HasForeignKey<Commodity>(b => b.OMSCommodityMaterialID);
});
```

Now in my `Commodity` endpoint (controller) I want to have a `GET` operator which retrieves all the field/values of the `Commodity` entity, but also all the values of the (related / referenced) `OmsCommodity` entity.

I am doing that as follow:

```
// GET: api/commodities
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<Commodity>> GetCommodities()
{
    return await this.Context.Commodity
        .Include(i => i.OmsCommodityMaterial)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

This is working fine, however I don't want to use my entity classes directly in my endpoint, and besides that I don't want to use all the fields of the (referenced) entity. 
In some of my other endpoints I used `AutoMapper` for mapping my entities to a DTO class/ViewModel. I thought it would be fairly simple to do that for the `GET` as well but I can't seem to get it to work.

I tried to map the `Commodity` DTO to my `Commodity/OmsCommodity` as follow:

**The DTO class:**

```
public class CommodityDTO
{
    public long CommodityID { get; set; }

    public long OMSCommodityMaterialID { get; set; }

    public decimal? SpecficWeight { get; set; }

    // Referenced entity part
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public long? SortOrder { get; set; }
}
```

**The (adjusted) GET endpoint:**

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetCommodities()
{
    var Commodities = this.Context.Commodity
        .Include(i => i.OmsCommodityMaterial);
    var commoditeDTO = _mapper.Map<IList<CommodityViewModel>>(Commodities);
    return Ok(commoditeDTO);
}
```

This returns the values / fields of the Commodity entity correctly, however the referenced values (`OmsCommodity`) all return NULL.

**AutoMapper setup is as follow:**

```
public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperProfile()
    {
        this.CreateMap<Commodity, CommodityViewModel>();
        this.CreateMap<CommodityViewModel, Commodity>();
    }
}
```

Probably I am doing something obvious wrong, but after several tests I can't seem to figure it out. Perhaps I should just do a `JOIN` on the referenced entity instead of the `.Include`?

I used the following tutorial as a reference by the way:
http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/06/26/aspnet-core-21-simple-api-for-authentication-registration-and-user-management

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to explicitly configure mapper where it should get the value for mapping from:

```
this.CreateMap<Commodity, CommodityViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(m => m.OmsCommodityMaterial.Name));
```

Comment: AutoMapper maps properties by convention. For related objects, that convention is to prefix the navigation property name. This is what AutoMapper calls projection. For example, if your DTO property was named `OmsCommodityMaterialName`, it would automatically map the value from `OmsCommodityMaterial.Name`. Since, the property is just `Name`, though, you have to tell AutoMapper explicitly how to handle the mapping as @AlexRiabov suggest here.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.